# Regex for matching duplicate consecutive punctuation characters with the exception of 3 periods

Tags: c#, .net, regex, punctuation

I have regex

```
(\p{P})\1
```

which successfully matches duplicate consecutive punctuation characters like

```
;;
,,
\\
```

, but i need to exclude  3  period (ellipsis) punctuation.

```
...
```

Comment: There are some good options already provided. One thing to be mindful of is that while regex is very powerful, it can be hard to go back to and maintain and for others to understand. So, you could just keep your regex simple and discard '...' when it is matched. It comes down to the specifics of your implementation and the level of regex knowledge as to which option is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful, as some approaches will not successfully match strings of the form `.##` (i.e. a '.' before repeating punctuation). Assuming that is something that should match.

This solution satisfies the following requirements: -

1. Repeated punctuation is matched.
2. Ellipsis (...) is not matched.
3. Two dots (..) and four or more dots are matched.
4. Repeated punctuation is matched when preceded or followed by dots, e.g. `.##`

This is the regex:

```
(?>(\p{P})\1+)(?<!([^.]|^)\.{3})
```

Explanation:

- `?>` means [atomic grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html). Specifically, throw away all backtracking positions. It means that if '...' fails to match, then don't step back and try and match '..'.
- `(\p{P})\1+)` means match 2 or more punctuation characters - you already had this.
- `(?<!([^.]|^)\.{3})` means search backwards from the end of the repeated character match and fail if you find three dots not preceded by a dot or beginning of string. This fails three dots while allowing two dots or four dots or more to work.

The following test cases pass and illustrate use:

```
string pattern = @"(?>(\p{P})\1+)(?<!([^.]|^)\.{3})";

//Your examples:
Assert.IsTrue( Regex.IsMatch( @";;", pattern ) );
Assert.IsTrue( Regex.IsMatch( @",,", pattern ) );
Assert.IsTrue( Regex.IsMatch( @"\\", pattern ) );
//two and four dots should match
Assert.IsTrue( Regex.IsMatch( @"..", pattern ) );
Assert.IsTrue( Regex.IsMatch( @"....", pattern ) );

//Some success variations
Assert.IsTrue( Regex.IsMatch( @".;;", pattern ) );
Assert.IsTrue( Regex.IsMatch( @";;.", pattern ) );
Assert.IsTrue( Regex.IsMatch( @";;///", pattern ) );            
Assert.IsTrue( Regex.IsMatch( @";;;...//", pattern ) ); //If you use Regex.Matches the matches contains ;;; and // but not ...
Assert.IsTrue( Regex.IsMatch( @"...;;;//", pattern ) ); //If you use Regex.Matches the matches contains ;;; and // but not ...            

//Three dots should not match
Assert.IsFalse( Regex.IsMatch( @"...", pattern ) );
Assert.IsFalse( Regex.IsMatch( @"a...", pattern ) );
Assert.IsFalse( Regex.IsMatch( @";...;", pattern ) );                        

//Other tests
Assert.IsFalse( Regex.IsMatch( @".", pattern ) );
Assert.IsFalse( Regex.IsMatch( @";,;,;,;,", pattern ) );  //single punctuation does not match                        
Assert.IsTrue( Regex.IsMatch( @".;;.", pattern ) );
Assert.IsTrue( Regex.IsMatch( @"......", pattern ) );                                       
Assert.IsTrue( Regex.IsMatch( @"a....a", pattern ) );
Assert.IsFalse( Regex.IsMatch( @"abcde", pattern ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid matching `...`

```
(?<![.])(?![.]{3})(\p{P})\1
```

Comment: +1, but why the `+`? To also allow triplicates and more repetitions? OK, but that's not what @n0mercy asked for.

Comment: @n0mercy are you trying to match 2 punctuation chars or n number of punctuations..

Comment: @Anirudh it is minimum 2 with an exception of triple dots

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<!\.)(?!\.{3}(?!\.))(\p{P})\1+
```

This will match any repeated punctuation (including `....` or `......` etc) unless it is the string `...`. For example:

```
; -- No Match
;; -- Match
,, -- Match
,,,, -- Match
\\ -- Match
... -- No Match
.... -- Match
```

Comment: This works for the additional requirement of ...., so upvote from me. I came up with something similar but you got there first.